# How to get property from object which is type of unknown

Tags: typescript

**How to get property from object which is type of unknown?**

---

I've tried to check if my `unknown` type variable is `null` (OK), if my variable is `typeOf` `object` (OK) but I can't check if it `hasOwnProperty()`. TS says that it is possible `null` even if I've just checked that it is not.

```js
const config: unknown = returnsUnknown();

//                                                   ↓ Error, TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
if (config !== null && typeof config === 'object' && config.hasOwnProperty("someProperty")) {
    console.log("Whoah! Here is my property!", config.someProperty);
}
```

---

Edit: As @krantni suggested optional chaining helped to fix my if statement.

```js
if (config !== null && typeof config === 'object' && config?.hasOwnProperty("someProperty")) 
{
    // TS2339: Property 'someProperty' does not exist on type 'object'. 
    console.log(config.someProperty);

    // TS7053: Property 'someProperty' does not exist on type '{}'.
    console.log(config["someProperty"]);
}
```

---

I am using TypeScript V 3.9.5

Answer (score 0):

In typescript 3.7, you could use optional chaining which will check for null:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

```
if (
  config !== null &&
  typeof config === 'object' &&
  config?.hasOwnProperty('someProperty')
) {
  console.log('Whoah! Here is my property!', config['someProperty']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It fixed my `if` statement but it didn't answer the question _How to get property...?_. I've updated my question.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. By checking for `typeof config === object` should let typescript infer that config is an object, but since it is a generic object, and using bracket notation will let you access the properties.
I'm not seeing the TS7053 error.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this:

```
const config: unknown = returnsUnknown();

if (config instanceof Object && "some property" in config) {
  const myValue = config["some property"]; // Access the property
}
```